# How do I get to this demand function in the monocentric city model?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, optimization, price, demand

I need to get this resulting price and quantity (housing):

[image: price and quantity functions]

It's pretty clear that the denominator of the quantity function is just the price function.

From this utility function:

[image: utility]

And this constraint:

[image: constraint]

Now this is a monocentric city model function, so these methods follow:

[image]

or:

[image]

However, I do not see the actual process of doing that. I need to make this calculations for other utility functions, but when I follow the steps, I do not get the desired result.

Comment: Are you sure the "results" at the beginning are correct? They seem to correspond to the utility function $c^\alpha q^{1-\alpha}$, while your utility function is $c^{1-\alpha}q^\alpha$.

Comment: I'm not sure until I can calculate the steps. I'm using a programme developed by someone else, so I'm trying to trace back the steps. If that is the case, I will change the "result" to match the correct utility function.

Comment: @Victor 'I'm using a programme developed by someone else' is that program publicly available?

Comment: The programme is mathematica, but the script is made by a journal article, where you can ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K:=y-(f+fa)-(t+ta)x$, and so $c=K-pq$.

From condition $(\mathrm{A1})$,
\begin{align}
&&\frac{v_q(\cdot)}{v_c(\cdot)}&=p \\
\quad\Rightarrow\quad &&
\frac{\alpha[K-pq]^{1-\alpha}q^{\alpha-1}}{(1-\alpha)[K-pq]^{-\alpha}q^\alpha}&=p \\
\quad\Rightarrow\quad &&
pq&=\alpha K \\
\quad\Rightarrow\quad &&
q&=\frac{\alpha K}{p}. \tag{*}
\end{align}
From $(\mathrm{A2})$ and $(*)$,
\begin{align}
&&[K-pq]^{1-\alpha}q^\alpha &= u \\
\quad\overset{(*)}{\Rightarrow}\quad 
&&[(1-\alpha)K]^{1-\alpha}\biggl(\frac{\alpha K}{p}\biggr)^\alpha &= u\\
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
&& (1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}\alpha^\alpha \frac{K}{u}&=p^\alpha. 
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
p(\cdot)&=\left[(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}\alpha^\alpha \frac{K}{u}\right]^{1/\alpha}\\
q(\cdot)&=\frac{\alpha K}{\left[(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}\alpha^\alpha \frac{K}{u}\right]^{1/\alpha}}
\end{align}

Comment: So in A2 you first substitute in the c from the constraint and then you substitute in all q's with the marshallian demand function. And then just solve for p and q respectively.

Comment: I've been trying to do this myself with the other utility function. c^a * q^(1-a) because it seems the programme was written with that despite their paper writing the other one, but I don't get the desired result either using that. Instead, I get p = -(a-1)K(u(aK)^(-a))^(1/1-a). Wondering what I'm getting wrong here.

Comment: @VictorNielsen: If utility is $c^\alpha q^{1-\alpha}$, then the only difference in $p(\cdot)$ is the outer-most exponent. You probably made some algebraic mistakes somewhere, and without seeing the steps, it's hard to tell exactly where you got tripped up.

Comment: if I switch around the q and c, then I get that the q in A1 is (K-aK)/p.
But if the equation's only difference is the exponent, how com your p(⋅) and q(⋅) be so different from the equations in the first picture in my post?

Comment: @VictorNielsen: $(K-\alpha K)/p=(1-\alpha)K/p$, which is similar to my $\alpha K/p$, except that $\alpha$ switches place with $(1-\alpha)$. And I don't think my results are very different from the coded expression in your post: switch $\alpha$ and $(1-\alpha)$ and plug in for $K$, you'll see they are the same.

Comment: I see it now. Seems pretty obvious now. I can tell it's been 3 years since I worked with equations. Thanks for all the help!